# I've a project created with VUE CLI and I've installed vue-electron-builder plugin

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-3, electron-builder, electron-vue

I've a vue project created with vue cli 3 and I've installed vue-electron-builder plugin to make electron app with vuejs. Now I've an existing electron app and I want to move the files from the existing electron app to the vue project but I'm confused :(

Answer (score 0):

Build your vue-electron5 project through https://github.com/kdydesign/vue-electron5
Then, insert the file associated with the vue from the renderer path and set it to the electron in the new project with the existing electron settings.